# any source code scanner to make sure all async calls are paired with await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there any c# source code scanner that will make sure all `async` function calls are prefixed with `await`? Visual Studio does not do it, nor does the compiler. I'm looking for some kind of utility that can find these offending calls.

Comment: `await` isn't the only way to correctly handle asynchronous functions, so your requirement is a bit too strict

Comment: Simple example of a common pattern where you want to get a reference to multiple independent `Task`'s before awaiting them: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fiU6Da. This would not be allowed by your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex wrote

> await isn't the only way to correctly handle asynchronous functions

But if you really want this .. You can add specific warning in the project properties [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014). If there is a place where you dont await a Task it does not allow you to build project and show errors.

[image]
[image]
[image]